# Render dynamic list of react components from array of strings

Tags: reactjs

My component is a Filter, that receives as a prop some filters, which should be rendered. However props are not rendered:

```
<Filter key={i}/>
```

Code is here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjI4MiSjlV69O_zaOCD

Filter component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Filter1 from './Filter1'
import Filter2 from './Filter2'


const Filters = ({ filters }) => (
  <div>
    { filters.reverse().map((Filter, i) =>
       // React.createElement(Filter, { key: i}) does not work
       // <p>{Filter}</p> // h
       <Filter key={i}/>

    )}
    <p> This should be seen twice!</p>
    <Filter1/>
    <Filter2/>
  </div>
)
Filters.propTypes = {
  filters: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired
}

export default Filters
```

One of the filters:

```
import React from 'react'

function Filter1 () {
  return (
    <h1>This is filter1</h1> 
  )
}

export default Filter1
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Can't render the elements dynamically, edited my question.

Comment: Do you have to use strings?

Comment: Yes, I get values from redux, so they should be serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Filters.js` like so:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Filter1 from './Filter1'
import Filter2 from './Filter2'

const filters = {
  Filter1: Filter1,
  Filter2: Filter2
}
const Filters = (props) => (
  <div>
    { props.filters.reverse().map((filter, i) => {
        const Filter = filters[filter];
        return <Filter key={i}/>
      })
    }
    <p> This should be seen twice!</p>
    <Filter1/>
    <Filter2/>
  </div>
)
Filters.propTypes = {
  filters: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired
}

export default Filters
```

The key change is using an object, `filters`, that contains keys that match up with the strings you pass in. The values are the components you want to render.

[Here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjIQ_Fx9z6VL2W0U1oh) is the edited webpackbin